# Schottky's Theorem - Sup is Max and more

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, normal-families

In an exercise I received there is the following question:

Let $R>0$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of functions $f \colon \{z:|z|<R\} \to \mathbb{C}$ that

1. are analytic
2. avoid the values $0,1$
3. all satisfy $f(0) = a_0$ for some constant $a_0 \in \mathbb{C}$

For all $0\leq r < R$ define
$$Q(r) := \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}\ [\max_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|]$$
I have to prove that $Q$ is continuous, unbounded and strictly increasing, and that $Q$ is in fact a **maximum**, in addition to being a supremum.

The strictly increasing part I managed to prove, using the fact that if $f$ is not constant, $f$'s maxima over growing sub-disks of $\{z:|z|<R\}$ must strictly increase, otherwise it is a contradiction to the maximum principle.

In addition, Schottky's theorem guarantees that $Q(r)$ is finite for all $0\leq r < R$.

But how to address the other things to prove? I tried the following direction:

By Montel's theorem, $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family. Let $0\leq r_0 < R$. By the definition of supremum, there exists a sequence $\{f_n\} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\max_{|z|\leq r} |f_n(z)| \to Q(r)$. By normality, there is a convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$. On the compact subset $|z| \leq r_0$, this sequence converges uniformly to some analytic function $g$, and the uniform converges yields $\max_{|z|\leq r} |g(z)| = Q(r)$. But I do not know whether $g \in \mathcal{F}$ (if it does, this solves the maximum part).

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean $f(0)=a_0$ for all $f\in \mathcal F?$ If so, it would be good to make this clearer.

Comment: @zhw. yes, fixed question.

Comment: Don't you need the maximum result to get strictly increasing? For example, if for $n=1,2,\dots,$ we define $f_n(x) = 1-1/(2n)+x/n$ on $[0,1],$ we see each $f_n$ is strictly increasing, while $\sup f_n(0) = \sup f_n(1)=1.$

Comment: @zhw. all functions must have the same value at $z=0$.

Comment: @zhw. BTW I found a way to prove that $g$ from the last paragraph in the question is in $\mathcal{F}$: using Hurwitz's theorem, one gets that $g \neq 0, 1$ and by convergence $g(0)=a_0$.

Comment: Right, but that's easily correctible: On $(-1,1),$ define $f_n(x) = x^{1/(2n+1)}, n=1,2,\dots $ Then $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n,$ the $f_n$ are strictly increasing, and $\sup f_n(1/2) = 1 = \sup f_n(3/4).$

Comment: @zhw. can you extend this example to $\{z : |z| < R\}$?